# Javascript functions in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the following error:

> "Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined
>   at Promise.all.then.result"

Also Getting Error

> "The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
>   To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
>   following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> ```
>  const firestore = new Firestore();
>   const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
>   firestore.settings(settings);
> ```
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
>   Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
>   need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> ```
>  // Old:
>   const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
>   // New:
>   const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
>   const date = timestamp.toDate();
> ```
>
> Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a
>   future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not
>   follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK."

However in my android project the place where i have defined the "Date" variable i have place the "@ServerTimestamp" on top.

Appreciate the help guys.

Code:

```
/*eslint-disable */

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document('notifications/{userEmail}/userNotifications/{notificationId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
const userEmail = context.params.userEmail;
const notificationId = context.params.notificationId;

    return admin.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(userEmail).collection("userNotifications").doc(notificationId).get().then(queryResult => {
        const senderUserEmail = queryResult.data().senderUserEmail;
        const notificationMessage = queryResult.data().notificationMessage;

        const fromUser = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(senderUserEmail).get();
        const toUser = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userEmail).get();

        return Promise.all([fromUser, toUser]).then(result => {
            const fromUserName = result[0].data().userName;
            const toUserName = result[1].data().userName;
            const tokenId = result[1].data().tokenId;

            const notificationContent = {
                notification: {
                    title: fromUserName + " is shopping",
                    body: notificationMessage,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, notificationContent).then(result => {
                console.log("Notification sent!");
                //admin.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(userEmail).collection("userNotifications").doc(notificationId).delete();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you write to the log as follows: `console.log(result[0].data()); console.log(result[1].data());`?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined at Promise.all.then.result" Are you sure you have the exact `userName` property and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the document you're request actually exists.  [data()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentSnapshot#data) will return undefined if it doesn't.  You can use the [exists](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentSnapshot#exists) property on the resulting DataSnapshot to check if a document was actually found.